# Not able to import the "urllib" library in jupyter note book?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib

Comment: What does your `import` line looks like?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: This probably has the answer you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050630/cannot-import-urllib-in-python/40050845

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below command

```py
pip install urllib3
```

[<<<Source>>>](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/)